# Cannot load WebGPU code: WGSL reader error

Tags: webgpu, wgsl

I'm following [this WebGPU tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTFFdZSDiTU&t=3172s), and I copied the below shader code (shader.wgsl, [full file is here](https://github.com/jack1232/webgpu03/blob/1653a1c9e987d0bf9bbc79c7b5eeaef25c14867c/src/shader.wgsl)):

```
// vertex shader

struct Output {
    @builtin(position) Position : vec4<f32>; // <-- error in this line
    @location(0) vColor : vec4<f32>;
};
```

I get an error in the dev console saying:

```
Tint WGSL reader failure: :4:44 error: expected '}' for struct declaration
    @builtin(position) Position : vec4<f32>;
```

Is this an error with the actual code, or with the way I'm loading it? I'm using [ts-shader-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-shader-loader) because I'm inside an Angular/TypeScript application.

The way I'm using the shader.wgsl file [can be seen here](https://github.com/jack1232/webgpu03/blob/1653a1c9e987d0bf9bbc79c7b5eeaef25c14867c/src/main.ts).

Any pointers as to what might be going wrong would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

structure fields in WGSL end with `,` not with `;`

```
struct Output {
    @builtin(position) Position : vec4<f32>,
    @location(0) vColor : vec4<f32>,
};
```

- [with error (using `;`)](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/resources/wgsl-offset-computer.html#x=5d000001007500000000000000003d8888623728a306fc320e1a9be64fe4a78fb96671b9a0bda23dffcbf6ab3aaf3cd5a1c6ffa67a3f5700c4effb41ec87bc398b8998d8979619f2df77b031beeef4dacf36adbfdc202f9984d821e89dd2cd48c7c78f182774189fafd33815dfffb2ed0000)
- [without error (using `,`)](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/resources/wgsl-offset-computer.html#x=5d000001007500000000000000003d8888623728a306fc320e1a9be64fe4a78fb96671b9a0bda23dffcbf6ab3aaf3cd5a1c6ffa67a3f5700c4effb41ec87bc398b8998d8979619f2df77b031beeef4daca491a666acf5323d23bbb0b6ec9b6810edefe77e3662545b3b99f515fffba90c000)

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems insane to use a comma to denote an end of statement. What on earth were the language devs thinking?!?

Comment: No idea but [rust uses commas for this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/structs.html) so it's certainly not unprecedented  ‍♂️

Comment: Ahh I've seen comments that the lang is similar to Rust. Given Rust was created by a Canadian, using a comma to denote an end of statement is a peculiar choice but I suppose it could be argued that this is similar to the way that a lot of Europeans use a comma and period in opposite ways when writing numbers e.g. $1,000 or €1.000 being a thousand dollars and a thousand euros respectively.

Comment: [typescript can also use commas](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAGnyiIYsIFcSAjBFgF8A3LlwBjNNShhKcJGkw5WxMpQDkAKSKoI6lgXacALAHYhwoA) though there it's optional as you can also use `;`